# Set kafka-consumer as a disaster recovery consumer in a consumer-group?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka infrastructure with topics having only one partition, 2 consumers would be subscribed to the partition. The first consumer is configured in the primary instance of an application, the second consumer is part of the disaster recovery instance of the application.

Now the problem here is, I want the second consumer to act as a fail-over consumer i.e. if the primary instance of the application consumer goes down, fail-over application's consumer should start consuming the messages.

One thing I could do is, on a second consumer side I can introduce a delay by calling a `Thread#Sleep`, this way the partition will be assigned to the primary instance

```
 // called at the consumer bean initialization
 void subscribeConsume() {
    // leaving exception handling for brevity
    if(application.type.equals("BackupApp"))  {
       TimeUnit.MINUTE.sleep(5);
    }
     ...
    // subscription logic
 }
```

But this seems to be a workaround/hack and not a robust solution. Are there any Kafka properties in the consumer library that could help here.